# Query filteration in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a list of products with the following details:

```js
"products": [{
    "product_name": "A",
    "product_type": [{
        "name": "Metal"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wood"
      },
      {
        "name": "Carbon"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "product_name": "B",
    "product_type": [{
        "name": "Metal"
      },
      {
        "name": "Iron"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "product_name": "C",
    "product_type": [{
        "name": "Metal"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wood"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "product_name": "D",
    "product_type": [{
      "name": "Wood"
    }],
  }
]
```

I want to filter this collection with

```
Product.find(query)
```

where sending *query = ["Wood", "Carbon"]*  should list me products which has either *Wood* or *Carbon* type.

Or works like:

```
Product.find({product_type: [ { name: query } ]}) list me products with name A, C and D
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) with [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to solve your problem:

```
Product.find({
  "product_type.name": {
    $in: ["Wood", "Carbon"]
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gk_PunaqKcX)

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like,

```
Product.find({product_name:{$in: [ 'A', 'C', 'D']}}) list me products with name A, C and D
```

Or if you want to find the documents based on product_type, then you can use following query

```
Product.find({
  "product_type.name": {
    $in: [
      "Metal"
    ]
  }
})
```

Refer: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vSfkpUjU494